# Rails STI and Active Record finds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sti

I have a set of classes something like this:

```
class Owner
  has_one :animal
end

class Animal < AR::Base
  TYPES = ['Lion','Cat']
  # has a type field

  belongs_to :owner
end

class Lion < Animal
  def speak
    'roar'
  end
end

class Cat < Animal
  def speak
    'meow'
  end
end
```

So I have an association with owners and animals, and each animal has a type.  This all works until I do a call like this:

```
owner.animal.speak
```

That returns an object of type 'Animal' and then attempts to call the method 'speak' which is undefined for the parent.  How do I get Rails to return the appropriate subclass instead of the parent class?

Comment: Do you have a column named "type" in animals table?

Comment: Are you sure the animal in question has a type? Are you validating presence of type?

Comment: Rails should initialize an instance of the correct subclass.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html
Are you sure you have your models set up correctly?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord and Arel don't easily handle subclasses like this. Your best bet is to have the Animal class keep track of it's own type internally. So:

```
class Animal < AR::Base
  TYPES = ['Lion','Cat']

  belongs_to :owner

  def speak
     case self.type
     when "Lion"
        "roar"
     when "Cat"
        "meow"
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: That's one solution.  I'm going to keep this open for a bit to see if anyone has come up with a more elegant one.  =)

Answer (score 0):

I just spun up a new Rails project and used your example, and it worked as expected. In your `type` column, are you sure that the type is `"Cat"` or `"Lion"` and not a lowercased or underscored version?

I would suggest adding `has_one :cat` and `has_one :lion` to `Owner`. Then, to instantiate them, you can call Rails' `owner.build_cat` which is the `has_one` way of building a new instance. (In `has_many` it would be `owner.cats.build`.)

This way, you are sure that the `type` is done correctly.

This is what I'm getting.

```
> owner.animal
=> nil
> owner.cat
=> nil
> owner.build_cat
=> #<Cat id: nil, owner_id: 1, type: "Cat" ...
> owner.cat.save
=> true
> owner.cat 
=> #<Cat id: 1, owner_id: 1, type: "Cat" ...
> owner.animal
=> nil # Whaaaa?
```

(The owner instance has an association cache, and since we've already called animal and it was nil, it has been cached as nil)

```
> owner.clear_association_cache
=> {}
> owner.animal
=> #<Cat id: 1, owner_id: 1, type: "Cat" ...
> owner.animal.speak
=> 'meow'
> owner.animal.class
=> Cat
> owner.animal.class.to_s == owner.animal.type
=> true
```

Hope that helps!